# SAS ODS. Set rute for export

Tags: sas, export, sas-ods

Currently I'm trying to export a Graph with ODS in a SAS guide enviroment. The problem is that we try to export the file on a rute, SAS introduces on the rute the pre-name /sas/config1/Lev1/SASApp/. Anyone knows if  it is possible to change this?.

ERROR: Pysical file does not exist, /sas/config1/Lev1/SASApp/....

```
ods listing close;
ods msoffice2k path="...............";
file='example.xls';

Proc gchar data=WORK.EXAMPLE;
....
...
....
run;
QUIT;
ODS msoffice2k close;
ods listing;
```

Thanks before-hand for the help,

Antonio Castillo

Comment: Just for clear, you are using SAS EG on Windows desktop, and you have server on Unix?

Comment: What is a `rute`?  You mean a path?

Comment: yes I mean path. Sorry. We already solved the problem. The problem was as you already noticed between that SAS EG on Windows desketop and the Unix Server.  Thanks for you time¡

Comment: @AntonioCastillo Then please either answer the question yourself or delete it.  (Answering yourself is preferable - provide enough detail that someone else having the same problem will find it helpful.)